# Visual Studio 2013 Start button doesn't include browser choices

Tags: visual-studio-2013

On one of my machines, the start button is titled "Start" and only launches the default browser as setup in VS.

[image: start button]

On my other machines, the button is titled with whatever browser is currently setup to launch in VS (ie "Google Chrome"). I believe this is the expected behavior.

This happens when using identical project files, so I believe it is something with the local PC's settings in VS rather than project setup.

Does anyone know how to correct this issue?

Comment: And see: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/481236/DefaultplusBrowserplusSwitcherplusinplusVisualplus

Comment: Make sure your Start-up project is a Web project.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. My startup project is a web project. If I hit start, it will build my site and launch IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating to VS 2013 Update 3, the issue is resolved.